# Can I retrieve all the SharePoint list items vis Microsoft Graph Api with 'Read items that were created by the user' turned on?

Tags: api, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

In the title there is most of the question. When working with Ms Graph Api I tried to get all the items from a Sp list using the`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items` endpoint. Now it worked fine with a test list which didn't have the 'Read items that were created by the user' turned on. Both lists have the same permissions sets and the user that makes the call is the owner so on that fron everything should be fine. When I go on the relevant list I also can see all the items as the owner, but making an api call returns an empty list and with that permission off it returns all of the items.

My question is if I can get all the items with that permission on somehow and if it's not possible then is there a way of turning this option off for a few moments using a different call to then retrieve items and turn it back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution has been found. To overwrite the 'Read items that were created by the user' permission I needed Sites.Manage.All scope added to the other I already had. Adding that scope let me download all the items no problem.